# Using SOA BPEL fault policies and binding in combination with BPEL catchAll

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel, fault

I have a scenario where I am calling a 3rd party rest service. I want that whenever there is a `remote fault` while calling the rest service BPEL should attempt 2 retries 30 seconds apart. If even the retries fail, control should go to the BPEL's `catchAll` block where I am processing the fault, sending an email notification etc.
Now the problem is if I use the fault policies and binding to configure the retries, the control doesn't go back to catchAll in the BPEL. I tried setting the `default failure action` as `rethrow fault` in `retry properties` but it ignores the catchAll block. If i don't use fault policies then on failure the control goes to catchAll but it do not attempt retry in case remote fault.
[[image: retry properties1]
Does SOA don't allow the use of fault policies and binding along with catchAll?